# How To build Multilevel Nested Comments System in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, comments

Im working on **Laravel Blog App** , in which I need multilevel nested comment below the blog post as displayed in photo.

[image]

Below is the Database migration schema for comments table

```
 Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned();
            $table->text('comment');
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Below is the Comment Model Class:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $table='comments';
    public $primaryKey='id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'parent_id',
        'comment',
        'post_id',
        'user_id'
    ];


    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Post');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\User');
    }

    public function replies() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Comment', 'parent_id');
    }
  }
```

Here is screenshot of `comments` table :

[image]

Im able to get only 1st level of reply using below code :

```
public function show($slug)
   {
   $post=Post::where(['slug'=>$slug])->with('user')->first();
    $comments=Comment::where(['post_id'=>$post->id,'parent_id'=>0])->orderBy('created_at','asc')->with('replies')->get();
    return response()->json($comments);
   }
```

Below is the response of above query :

[image]

As you see in reponse , im getting only 2 replies in comment id 7 , but in database comment id 10 to 16 are reply of reply of comment ....that is not displaying ...I want to fetch and display that .

I have searched many question on StackOverflow and Google but not found any useful resource . Please Help me to solve this .

Comment: Use `->with('replies.replies')` for another level iof comments. And add another '.replies' for the next level and so on. Recursive data structures are very hard to solve with sql (although some sqls actually have recursive queries) and are considered antipatterns. I suggest you google it and maybe rethink your database design a bit.

Comment: But if you're going to stick to the current design you could add `protected $with = 'replies';` to your comment model, which will recursively fetch all children. I suggest against that and maybe rethink the UX instead (for example autoload up to 2 levels and then load more on xlick). Bit there is that option.

Comment: @devk , i would like to thank you , your hint is very helpful for me .

Answer (score 0):

edit the relationship in the comment model to the following in order to get multilevel replies  .
For me this wasn't the problem, the problem I faced was how to limit the level of replies and still look for a solution;

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Comment', 'parent_id')->with('replies');
```